# Do we indeed need "all" target in a Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have found the following code from http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

My question is: Do we really need the line

```
all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

?

What will be wrong if I do not keep the line or does it have some other purpose?

Comment: it's somewhat traditional to have it. especially on larger projects where you might have MANY sub-components that can be compiled individually. `make some_minor_little_bit` while working on that small component, then `make all` when you're ready to test the entire package, v.s. having to do `make sub1 sub2 sub3 .... sub999`.

Comment: Suppose if I define `SOURCES2=hello.cpp` and then `all: $(SOURCES2)  $(EXECUTABLE)` will the Makefile compile _hello.cpp_ only?

Comment: No as explained in my answer `$(EXECUTABLE)` is dependent on `$(SOURCES)` through the suffix rule `.cpp.o:`. If you wanted to only compile _hello.cpp_ you could run `make hello.o`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From the perspective of the behavior of make**

The line:

```
all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

is special in this case as it is the first target defined in the Makefile. Since there is no `.DEFAULT_GOAL` defined that makes it the default goal and so what make will aim to build if no target is specified on the command line.

In this specific case all its presence is serving it to allow you to use the command `make all`.

It is also ensuring that `make all`  and `make` will not work as expected if there is a file called *all* present as make will consider that when evaluating the rule. 
The normal practice is to define such targets as [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) so that they will not be effected by the presence of a file with their name.

For example: `.PHONY : all`.

The reasons it does not serve any other purpose in this example are:

- `$(SOURCES)` is a redundant dependency as `$(EXECUTABLE)` depends on it already through `$(OBJECTS)` which depends on `$(SOURCES)` through the [suffix rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html) `.cpp.o:`
- The other dependence `$(EXECUTABLE)` is the next target defined, so removing the all target will make `$(EXECUTABLE)` the default goal.

**From the perspective of convention**

The `all` target is a [Standard Target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html) and "should be the default target".

Some users and tools may assume the target all is present. 
For example the IDE eclipse by default expects Makefiles to have the target `all` which it will use for incremental builds. Without the all target extra configuration is required for eclipse  be able to build the project.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `make` without specifying a target, it will run the first target in the file. It's a convention that this target is responsible for creating a deployable file (package or executable) for installation on your platform. The name `all` is simply a  [convention](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Standard-Targets.html) (at least in the GNU project), and could be anything you like (for example `$(name)`, `compile` or `deployable`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the `$(SOURCES)` variable appears as a prerequisite of the `all` target.  That's pretty useless.

In your case, since you have only one executable, it's not necessary to have `all`.  But many makefiles built multiple "final targets" which do not depend on each other.  In that case it's traditional to have an `all` target which depends on them all so you can build them all with one command.

And since it's traditional, people put it into makefiles with only one target as well, for consistency.